# Android-get all json items from api that's organized by pages

Tags: android, json, rest

So I'm working with this api url : https://blahblah/api/api_key/cars?
The problem is that when this is launched, I only get the cars that are in page 1/the default page.

However by doing this : https://blahblah/api/api_key/cars/page2  I'd only get the cars in page 2.

Is there a way I can get all cars from all pages?
How can I get the jsonObject of all the cars in all pages at once(supposedly, there are 20 pages)?

Thanks.

Comment: So your question is not related to Android?

Comment: It is, because I'm doing it in Android studio

Comment: I think you should do multiple requests there is no way one requests can have multiple links or if you are the one developing the API change it to fit your needs.

Comment: It depends how your api `api/api_key/cars` is designed. Just ask the api developer whether you can get all items in one go (most likely by api design, it is not supported to prevent load on your server, there might be millions of record. Also the api user might not want to see all records, but some like newest, or top 100 etc.). There should be a limit params as well in the api, so sending `api/api_key/cars?limit=100` will return 100 items, but it still doesn't guarantee that you will get all items.

Comment: @Xenolion, thanks for your input. No I'm not the developer. If it's not possible then yeah I think I'll have to do multiple requests.

Comment: @HemantPatel, thanks for your input. I think you're right. I'll check and see if there is a limit parameter.